# Regex for capture lines starting with numbers

Tags: regex

In Ubuntu, take the file /etc/passwd as an example. I'm trying to capture the lines 41-46 through a regex. I'm using this command:

```
nl /etc/passwd | grep 4[1-6]
```

The output is this:

```
17  ******41:41************************************************************
29  ************46*********************************************************
41  ***********************************************************************
42  ***********************************************************************
43  ***********************************************************************
44  ***********************************************************************
45  ***********************************************************************
46  ***********************************************************************
```

The " * " are the content of the file (I replaced it with the " * " to not show them).

So, the regex also captured the lines 17 and 29, in this case. How can I capture only the line numbers that I have specified (in this example, lines 41-46)?

I tried using the "^" in various combinations, but it didn't work, like in "grep (^4[1-6]) ".

Comment: AFAIK - `grep` and `regex` have different syntax and I think  your example doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't know about that. I thought both used the same syntax. Seems I'll have to think on another solution

Answer (score 0):

`^`, `[` and `]` have special meaning, you have to escape them or use `-P` option (PCRE)

```
grep \^4\[1-6\]
```

or

```
grep -P ^4[1-6]
```

or, a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ane 'print $_ if /^4[1-6]/' input_file
```

Comment: None of the expressions brings results. If I put them after the pipe (|), there are no results.

Comment: man sed or man grep -> `-E` for extended regexp's - the need for escaping is drastically reduced among other things.